# Losing Firebase custom claims on mobile login

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using custom claims in Firebase to set admin and organization id to help me with authorization and multi tenant.

Recently I've noted that custom claims are being cleared, becoming undefined without any reason.

Analysing the problem, trying to reproduce it, i've noted that when the user do logout and login using **mobile**, the custom claims are being set to undefined.

This behavior may occur doing logout and login on web, but I couldn't reproduce it on web yet.

I'm using a frontend view to manage and set admin and organizationId custom claims values, calling a backend Cloud Function to do this. This is working fine, and the values are being set well. But when the user do the logout and login at a mobile, these custom claims become undefined, as I can see through the frontend view mentioned above.

**Steps**

1. Set custom claims (admin=true and organizationId="companyXYZ") to userA
2. userA sign in the web app with mobile
3. userA custom claims (admin and organizationId) remain setted with original values
4. userA signs out
5. userA signs in again and custom claims (admin and organizationId) modified to undefined

Any ideas?

**Login code**

```
doLogin(value){
 let t = this;

 return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
  localStorage.removeItem("user");
   firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(value.email, value.password)
   .then(res => {
    var user = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
      if (user) {
        t.setUser(user);
        resolve(user);
      } else {
        reject('No user logged in');
      }
    })
    resolve(res);
   }, err => reject(err))
 }) 
}
    setUser(user: any){
        let u: FirebaseUserModel = new FirebaseUserModel();
        u.image = user.photoURL;
        u.name = user.displayName;
        u.provider = user.providerData[0].providerId;
        u.email = user.email;
        u.uid = user.uid;
        user.getIdTokenResult().then ((idTokenResult) => {
          console.log(idTokenResult.claims)
          u.admin = idTokenResult.claims.admin? true: false;
          u.organizationId = idTokenResult.claims.organization;
        })
      }
```

**Logout code**

```
doLogout(){
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       if(firebase.auth().currentUser){
         //this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
         this.afAuth.signOut();
         resolve();
       }
       else{
         reject();
       }
     });
   }
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by "cleared".  Client app code can't at all influence the values set in custom claims.  That can only be change using privileged backend code.  Please edit the question to more clearly explain what you're observing, and how that's different than what you expect.

Comment: Hi Doug. 

Thanks for your quick answer.

When I say "cleared" I mean that the custom claims become undefined.

I'm using a frontend view to manage and set admin and organizationId custom claims values, calling a backend Cloud Function to do this. This is working fine, and the values are being setted well.

But when the user do the logout and login at a mobile, these custom claims become undefined, as I can see through the frontend view mentioned above.

Comment: Why do you expect custom claims to be available after the user signs out?  When the user signs out, **everything** about that account is cleared from the client app until they sign in again.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not being clear. I don't expect to use custom claims after user signs out. 

The problem is that when the user sign in again, I must check the organizationId and if he is an admin user, but the custom claims are undefined.


Before doing sign out, the custom claims are setted well. Then the user do the sign out,  and everything is cleared from the client app. But when the user signs in again, the custom claims are undefined.

Comment: This is all information that you should explain in the question itself.  I suggest editing it and explain step by step what you are doing, and how the result is different than what you expect.

Comment: I had a similar problem but I realized that I had two different codes setting user claims and they were not reusing the previous claims. I fixed it by adding the previous from the user object: `auth.setCustomUserClaims(userId, { ...user.customClaims, role });`